# How To Delete All Shapes in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I want to delete all shape in word. How can I do?
Please help me.

I marked in red to see: 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: `for each shp in document.shapes shp.delete`?

Answer (score 5):

VBA is one way to do it. Follow these steps:

- Developer tab
- Macros (new title as "RemoveShapes" (or whatever you want))
- click "plus"
- copy/paste (below)
- run (just select that macro next time)

---

```
For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1  
    ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Delete  
Next i
```

credit: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a514a54a-fc33-4c8b-9e9c-1f179b5e1d46/word-vba-to-delete-all-shapes?forum=isvvba

[image: removing shapes]